# Error: Uncaught Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename when installing electron app on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, electron

I'm creating an Electron app and when I try to install it on a Windows 7 32-bit machine I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'D:\final-app\library\db\tmp_login.db~' -> 'D:\final-app\library\db\tmp_login.db'
```

I tried to

1. run `cmd.exe` as an administrator
2. run `npm cache clean --force`
3. run `npm install -g npm@latest --force`

But I'm still getting the same error. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my situation it helped on windows:

clean cache with

```
npm cache clean --force
```

install the latest version of npm globally as admin:

```
npm install -g npm@latest --force
```

clean cache with

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Try to install your component once again.

[npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename)