# Can't install NPM dependencies on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10, enoent

Not too sure what's changed with Node.js and NPM recently (i.e. in the last several days) but I can't seem to find a way to install `node_modules` dependencies for any projects using Node.js on Windows 10 anymore...

My current setup is as follows:

`Node.js: v9.5.0
 NPM: v5.6.0
 Vue.js: v2.9.3`

I've tried clearing the cache prior to install: `npm cache clear -f`

Any time I attempt to run `npm i` or `npm install` I'm presented with the following list of errors:

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents): 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules\.staging\fsevents-a6c1bd51\node_modules\abbrev' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules\.staging\abbrev-3ab84c45'

npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules\acorn
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules\acorn' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules\.acorn.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\mbosse\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-02-14T18_27_56_988Z-debug.log
```

The specified debug.log contains the follow:

> 19859 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3
>   (node_modules\fsevents):
>
> 19860 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules.staging\fsevents-a6c1bd51\node_modules\abbrev' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules.staging\abbrev-3ab84c45'
>
> 19861 verbose optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>
> 19861 verbose optional Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
>
> 19862 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules\acorn' -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules.acorn.DELETE'
>
> 19863 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample
>
> 19864 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
>
> 19865 verbose argv "C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\ProgramFiles\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "i"
>
> 19866 verbose node v9.5.0
>
> 19867 verbose npm  v5.6.0
>
> 19868 error path C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules\acorn
>
> 19869 error code ENOENT
>
> 19870 error errno -4058
>
> 19871 error syscall rename
>
> 19872 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules\acorn' ->  'C:\xampp\htdocs\vue-scrolling-table-sample\node_modules.acorn.DELETE'
>
> 19873 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> 19874 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]

So it seems, for some reason, NPM is incapable of renaming `node_modules` dependencies. 
I've tried rolling back NPM to earlier version (in case npm@latest is not stable enough).

Using `nvm` I've completely uninstalled all versions of Node.js and NPM and reinstalled them. I've since tried installing my dependencies on a Node.js v6.11.3 setup as well as a Node.js v8.9.4 with the identical outcome.

Any suggestions would be very beneficial, thank you!

Comment: Many tutorials say this happens due to race-conditions and running `npm install` multiple times eventually resolves the issue. 
This isn't the case as it's always the same module that fails, never getting any further in the dependency install process.

Comment: Try `yarn`, it often works better in windows environment.

Comment: Part of me is just curious if anyone else is experiencing this issue!
Honestly been thinking about setting up a Linux Mint OS on a bootable USB drive. That way I can always develop in a Linux environment where permissions make more sense.

Comment: @wostex, I've tried following your suggestion. Now using yarn on my project which seems to generate the `node_modules` and `.lock` file correctly for all but my forked dependency.

Answer (score 3):

Possible duplicate => [npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename)

Steps:

1. npm cache clean --force
2. npm install

If and only IF this doesn't work what I did was erasing the node_modules folder and package-lock.json (if you have the last one) and repeat steps 1 and 2

Comment: Thanks. cache clean seems to resolve this error.

Comment: I did try all the above, still no luck, any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If possibly you have renamed your package.json and the name does not match your package-lock.json

To resolve this error open your package.json and package-lock.json to check if the "name" key has the same value.

If not change then change them to match your project name.

Example if your project name is todo-list then the "name" value can be todo-list. Note, this is not compulsory.