# Error When I try to use NPM install package.json file

Tags: git, npm

[image: Linked to the error screenshot]

above is the screenshot for the error from git. I just simply type npm install, and it keeps giving me those errors. How should I fix it? many thanks

Comment: seems to be related to your antivirus https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your project is cloned in a OneDrive folder, and that may cause the issue as npm downloads lots of files on install. Try cloning and running `npm install` elsewhere, that may work.

Comment: I solved the error by downloading the original files from github and install the packages again, then everything went well. thanks for your help