# Angular Version 8 - Every effort to do NG NEW ends in npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink

Tags: angular

I run the following commands as administrator on a standard Windows 10.

I installed angular (ver 8), as per book...

```
D:\>npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\ThinkInCode\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\ThinkInCode\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@8.3.8 postinstall C:\Users\ThinkInCode\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@8.3.8
added 244 packages from 185 contributors in 155.387s

D:\>cd wamp64\www\NGAPPS\UDEMY

D:\wamp64\www\NGAPPS\UDEMY>ng --version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.8
Node: 12.11.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.803.8
@angular-devkit/core         8.3.8
@angular-devkit/schematics   8.3.8
@schematics/angular          8.3.8
@schematics/update           0.803.8
rxjs                         6.4.0
```

The went on to creating my project...

```
D:\wamp64\www\NGAPPS\UDEMY>ng new NG8-APP --routing
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE NG8-APP/angular.json (3617 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/package.json (1283 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/README.md (1025 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/tsconfig.json (543 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/tslint.json (1953 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/.editorconfig (246 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/browserslist (429 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/karma.conf.js (1021 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/tsconfig.app.json (270 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/index.html (294 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/polyfills.ts (2838 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/test.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/app/app-routing.module.ts (246 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/app/app.module.ts (393 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/app/app.component.html (25530 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (1107 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/app/app.component.ts (213 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/e2e/protractor.conf.js (810 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (642 bytes)
CREATE NG8-APP/e2e/src/app.po.ts (262 bytes)
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@~8.2.9 (sha1-8BQhStPcbrC/OVzSgpMWPQd6p7Q=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @angular/core@~8.2.9 (sha1-tOUwPWkijTA2KmShrkX46IpfLiQ=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for typescript@~3.5.3 (sha1-yDD2V/k/HqhGgZ6SkJL1/lmD6Xc=) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path D:\wamp64\www\NGAPPS\UDEMY\NG8-APP\node_modules\.staging\@angular\core-3db91d17\fesm2015\core.js
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\wamp64\www\NGAPPS\UDEMY\NG8-APP\node_modules\.staging\@angular\core-3db91d17\fesm2015\core.js'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\wamp64\www\NGAPPS\UDEMY\NG8-APP\node_modules\.staging\@angular\core-3db91d17\fesm2015\core.js'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\wamp64\www\NGAPPS\UDEMY\NG8-APP\node_modules\.staging\@angular\core-3db91d17\fesm2015\core.js'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'D:\\wamp64\\www\\NGAPPS\\UDEMY\\NG8-APP\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\core-3db91d17\\fesm2015\\core.js'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'D:\\wamp64\\www\\NGAPPS\\UDEMY\\NG8-APP\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\core-3db91d17\\fesm2015\\core.js'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\wamp64\\www\\NGAPPS\\UDEMY\\NG8-APP\\node_modules\\.staging\\@angular\\core-3db91d17\\fesm2015\\core.js',
npm ERR!   parent: 'NG8-APP'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ThinkInCode\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-10T17_09_33_041Z-debug.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

For a whole day, no amount of effort has yielded a successful installation...

I have **disabled the antivirus** and *severally* **repeated the install**, also **reboot my machine**, ensured **VS Studio Code is closed**..., run `npm cache clean`, then `npm cache clean --force`, then manually deleted both **npm cache** and **npm** folders under the **%APPDATA%** path and then **reinstalled angular** with `npm install -g @angular/cli` all to the same **EPERM** error,... different files but same error.

I have read somewhere recommendations to downgrade to **ver. 7**, but I can't because I need angular **ver. 8**... Besides, ver. 8 should install successfully somehow! I also need a fairly recent **Node.js** because of a certain **React Native** project. What on earth should I do differently?? Pls help.

Comment: did you try running `cmd` as admin

Comment: @jitender sure did that. That's how I begun with the post above... Thanks

Comment: oh I didn't notice that :)

Comment: do you have a custom .npmrc?

Comment: @pixelbits nothing custom... Just the exact procedure above, friend

Comment: Possibly this could help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45840283/6635464

Comment: I found this, maybe it can help you? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12726#issuecomment-451400403

Comment: What is your node js version ?

Comment: @TonyNgo as you can confirm in the post it is Node ver. 12.11.0

Comment: use lts version

Comment: You installing @angular/cli globally on D: drive. Maybe it confuses the system: `D:\>npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\ThinkInCode\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\ThinkInCode\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
` Do you have the same issue if locate project on C: drive or don't use -g flag on D: ?

Comment: @Anna... I humbly disagree. Installing globally using -g flag installs to the system %AppData% path, irrespective of which drive am on while issuing the command...

Comment: Is Angular a serious framework anymore if an error or bug can persist for so long without any documented way of resolving it?

Comment: @EdNdee It's not caused by the framework - it's probably caused by running the commands with sudo access, which may mess up your file permissions.

Answer (score -2):

Try to uninstall the CLI using:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

and reinstall using:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```