# Not able to install bootstrap in react app

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, npm-install, react-bootstrap

[image: Screenshot of error in command prompt]

I am new to React JS, i have started an online course for react. I followed the steps from the tutorials and encountered this error. Also i checked some solutions on this platform of question posted by others. Please can someone tell me the solution? thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Did you run the CMD as an administrator ?

Comment: Yes, installing as normal user was giving the same error.

Comment: did u try kill all process(folders, editors etc.) and try to install?

Comment: can you try solutions suggested on this thread ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename

Comment: Try installing yarn https://yarnpkg.com/ and run the command `yarn add packagename`

Comment: i tried many solutions, but i am getting the same error

Comment: Please read [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) it states _"**DO NOT post images of** code, data, **error messages**, etc -  **copy or type the text into the question [instead]**"_. Many of the reasons for not doing this are listed in [why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question#answer-285557). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62280195/edit) your question and replace the image of the error message with text instead.

Answer (score 1):

install the following package:

- tsutils
- jquery
- popper

I recommend you install  Material-UI it's faster and easier web development.

All you need is to visit their web site: 
[material-ui.com](https://material-ui.com/)