# React is not getting installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install react by npm but its giving me this error

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile 'C:\\Users\\Bilal\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v6\\npm-request-2.88.2-d73c918731cb5a87da047e207234146f664d12b3-integrity\\node_modules\\request\\lib\\cookies.js' -> 'G:\\my-react\\node_modules\\request\\lib\\cookies.js'".
```

I have used tons of commands nothing working

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and what I did was to use this command instead so that It don't copyfile from local cache

```
create-react-app your_app_name --use-npm --cache /tmp/empty-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible Solution :

```
1. Download latest recommended version of NodeJS
2. Uninstall current version from Control Panel
3. Go to C:\Users\{YourUsername}\AppData\Roaming folder and delete npm and npm-cache folders
4. Run installer of NodeJS
5. Update NPM to latest with npm i -g npm@latest command line
```

Comment: try rolling back to node version 5

Answer (score 0):

I changed the directory from `C` to another one and it worked. Maybe the issues were with installing packages in the root drive.

Answer (score 0):

i have some problem before so i try this and working,

if you use avast! antivirus or another antivirus, you must disable before create-react-app

Answer (score -2):

Do you have antivirus active on your pc? if so, try disabling it and retry the command npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: There's already another answer suggesting to disable the antivirus, no need to add another one. Thanks.