# React project fails to build after rpm run command due to error code ELIFCYCLE

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I came across some error when I tried to run my react project in localhost, **can anyone help me**?
Here is the error log:

```
C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\burger-project>npm start

> burger-project@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Intel\Desktop\burger-project
> node scripts/start.js

Plugin could not be registered at 'html-webpack-plugin-before-html-processing'. Hook was not found.
BREAKING CHANGE: There need to exist a hook at 'this.hooks'. To create a compatibility layer for this hook, hook into 'this._pluginCompat'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! burger-project@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the burger-project@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Intel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-28T20_10_02_050Z-debug.log
```

can anyone tell if the webpack version and html-webpack-plugin are compatible over here or I need to do some changes with the versions? Or change version of any other package? Any help would be appreciated.

here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "burger-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.3.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "4.10.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.5",
    "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "jest": "^26.4.2",
    "npm-upgrade": "^2.0.4",
    "object-assign": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
    "promise": "8.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "raf": "3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.8.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve": "1.6.0",
    "style-loader": "0.19.0",
    "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node",
      "mjs"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^1.0.2",
    "css-loader": "^4.2.1",
    "html-webpack-beforehtml-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try doing this: https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/preload-webpack-plugin/issues/86#issuecomment-454720065

Comment: @Axnyff, it didn't work

Comment: It also may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename/57441556

Answer (score 1):

Well same problem here after installing typescript, but I deleted the package-lock.json e installed the dependencies npm install next react react-dom and then it worked.