# How to fix problem with axios version 0.18.0

Tags: reactjs, axios

Axios was running fine but today I try to run my react app and get the error

> ./node_modules/axios/lib/helpers/cookies.js Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read

I have tried uninstalling and installing it again but it still persists.

Any help would be highly valued.

Comment: There were no errors when uninstalling or reinstalling? Because that error is saying that the user which is running the react app does not have permission to read that file.

Comment: It could be many things, why don't you start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename