# Error (Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'path')

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, rename

I receive the following error when trying to rename a folder in VS Code on Windows.

When I try to rename a folder, I get the following error that pops up in the bottom right corner:

```
Error: EPERM operation not permitted, rename 'path'
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename)

Answer (score -2):

Try running that from a command-line interface

```sh
Rename  dir_oldname  dir_newname
```

If this doesn't work try increasing the permissions of the folder, then rerunning the thing!

```sh
chmod -R 777 dir_name
```

As you are saying you are new to development, I'll also tell you how to open your command line

You must have an app named command prompt (Windows) or terminal (mac), open the application, and write the following into the window before executing anything

```sh
cd ".."
```

Comment: Why when I text cd "One Directory Up The Working Dir" at cmd its say The system cannot find the path specified?.

Comment: Bijak it means that you need to replace it with the path to the parent directory, or for simple usage, you can also replace it with '..'

Comment: I made it easier for your usage by editing the issue :-) @Bijak

Comment: Yoo, Thanks for helping beginner like me :)