# Is there a way to troubleshoot this error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, linux-mint

The node version: 16.4.0
Npm version: 7.18.1

I'm installing it in an removable drive, if that changes anything, using Linux mint (x86_64), hp being the computer name (only for you to know why there is it over the error)
error message:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../browserslist/cli.js
npm ERR! dest /media/hp/PenName/SiteJs/node_modules/.bin/browserslist
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../browserslist/cli.js' -> '/media/hp/penName/SiteJs/node_modules/.bin/browserslist'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../browserslist/cli.js' -> '/media/hp/penName/SiteJs/node_modules/.bin/browserslist'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../browserslist/cli.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/media/hp/penName/SiteJs/node_modules/.bin/browserslist'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hp/.npm/_logs/2021-06-24T14_37_31_882Z-debug.log
```

That's it please help if you know how

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600932/npm-eperm-operation-not-permitted-on-windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename