# Installing font-awesome in angular having this error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, fonts, font-awesome

Installing font-awesome in angular having this error

```
  npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\pratish.devangan\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\GEINE UI\GEINE_Platform\node_modules@babel\plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\pratish.devangan\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\GEINE UI\GEINE_Platform\node_modules@babel.plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding-kX6eCJ6w
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, rename 'C:\Users\pratish.devangan\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\GEINE UI\GEINE_Platform\node_modules@babel\plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding' -> 'C:\Users\pratish.devangan\OneDrive - HCL Technologies Ltd\Desktop\GEINE UI\GEINE_Platform\node_modules@babel.plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding-kX6eCJ6w'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\pratish.devangan\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-05-12T07_44_55_523Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename)

Answer (score 0):

You should use this package:

```
npm i @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome
```

Doucmentation Link:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome