# npm install not installs package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, npm

I had the error:

> npm error npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

I followed the steps, which are described on geeksforgeeks.

1. npm cache clean --force
2. delete node_modules
3. delete package-lock.json
4. npm install

The node_modules are installed again, but package-lock.json doesen't appears again in the project directory. In the console I have the error:

> npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! syscall rename npm ERR! path
> C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json.4215348391
> npm ERR! dest
> C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json
> npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,
> rename
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json.4215348391'
> -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json'
> npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json.4215348391'
> -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json']
> {   npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json.4215348391'
> -> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json']
> {      npm ERR!     errno: -4048, npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!
> syscall: 'rename', npm ERR!     path:
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json.4215348391',
> npm ERR!     dest:
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json'
> npm ERR!   }, npm ERR!   errno: -4048, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM', npm
> ERR!   syscall: 'rename', npm ERR!   path:
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json.4215348391',
> npm ERR!   dest:
> 'C:\xampp\htdocs\webshop_ts_mern\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\package.json',

Comment: 1. It's package-lo**ck**, not lo**g**. 2. The output you show has errors with the installation. So, is the issue that package-lock.json is not there or that the installation doesn't work at all? 3. The errors seem like wrong permissions to the file system.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for your response. I try it again.

Comment: It could also be a permission issue, have you tried running the command prompt as Administrator?

Comment: @node_modules. Done that, is is now installed. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename)

Comment: @EmanueleScarabattoli It works with running the command prompt as Administrator. Thanks