# pnpm install: ERR_PNPM_LINKING_FAILED ("operation not permitted, rename[...]")

Tags: node.js, npm, pnpm

I started on a completely fresh Windows (11) system, installed Node, pnpm and so on. When running `pnpm install`, I've got the following error:

> "ERR_PNPM_LINKING_FAILED Error: EPERM: oprtation not permitted, rename [...]":
>
> [image]

- pnpm version: 8.7.6
- node version: 18.18.0

It seems like from time to time this issue comes up because one can find several discussions about similar topics:

- [ERR_PNPM_LINKING_FAILED when running pnpm install in Docker on macOS](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/7024)
- [npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename)

The second one looked promising but removing `node_modules`, `pnpm prune` and so on did not help in my case. I also checked the permissions for the directory, ran the commands in the admin PoweShell, did the same within the Git Bash but the error is still there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turned out that the **pnpm version 8.7.6** seems to be the problem. I found two ways to solve/mitigate the problem:

- **use another pnpm version... I saw that pnpm v8.8.0 was released in the meantime and tested it. It looks like the error is gone (`npm install -g pnpm@8.8.0` or `npm install -g pnpm@latest`) otherwise a downgrade would also help**
- running `pnpm install` again and again until it completes without erros is also a workaround. Every time you execute the command another package will throw the error until all problems are solved.

Comment: yeah, bit worrying hold your nose until the error goes away... it still does this with an upgrade from `pnpm 8.7.6` to `pnpm 8.10.5`

Comment: Had an error in 8.6.12 now don't in 8.11.0

Comment: also on windows close the vscode window. sometimes it also produce issue

Answer (score 2):

Given that nobody actually pinpointed the cause of this problem, I created an account just to answer this question.

Proof of solution: [**see a screenshot of the solution here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXK6R.png)

The underlying cause of the problem is a conflict between processes: if there are different processes trying to access the same folder/files, then rewriting/deleting/moving such folder/files while other processes are still accessing them is not permitted.

Therefore the fix to this problem on Windows is to close everything that may be accessing the directory you're trying to work with. Or directly end these processes with the Task Manager.

For example, if you have VS Code on, close it.
If you need to restart the machine just to make sure, do it.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be the answer for everyone, however, it worked for me on Mac.

1. I uninstalled PNPM with NPM `npm un -g pnpm`.
2. I installed PNPM with Homebrew, `brew update && brew install pnpm`
3. Any link or symlink issues should be resolved easily from advice provided during the `pnpm` installation.

   — Just in case here is a fix that can be tweaked to your specific needs.

   ```
   ln -s ../Cellar/pnpm/<PNPM_VERSION>/bin/pnpm pnpm
   ln -s ../Cellar/pnpm/<PNPM_VERSION>/bin/pnpx pnpx
   ```

Using Homebrew has worked well for me so far.  Also, I believe keeping the number of global NPM packages to be for the better.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can also be caused when using `pnpm deploy /path/here` and using a path such as `/dev/myapp` for example (this path is reserved for device files).

Double check where you're deploying/installing pnpm.