# Unable to close the auth folder within the parenthesis in my Next.js project

Tags: next.js

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\dell\Desktop\Projects\nextp1\nextp1\src\app\auth' -> 'c:\Users\dell\Desktop\Projects\nextp1\nextp1\src\app(auth)'

whenever i try to enclose the foldername within the parenthesis it shows the above error.
please help me to resolve this issue

I just want to rename this folder from auth to (auth)

Comment: You cannot change the name of a file while it is opened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293636/npm-err-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-rename)